# Распарсить многомерный массив json

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

Я видел уже один пример, но в моём случае выдаёт undefined (возможно я гдет накосячил).
Есть такой массив `[{"name":"\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441","last_n":"\u041b\u0435\u0431\u0435\u0434\u0435\u0432","avatar":"\/user\/0M\/0K\/2\/pictures\/avatar\/8c16432d87bec8614f709ddba.jpg"},{"name":"\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441","last_n":"lot","avatar":"css\/ico\/avatar.jpg"}]`

Это чтот подобное поискового поля на форуме, сервер возвращает от 0-5 массивов сжатыми в один массив json надо  распарсить каждый массив и поместить в разные div... Вот формирование ответа сервером

```
if(!empty($bean)){
  $datu = array();
foreach ($bean as $var) {
  $sdah  = //тут крч запрос;
$smpt = array(
"name" => $var->login_1,
"last_n" => $var->login_2,
"avatar" => $sdah->avatar
);
array_push($datu, $smpt);
}
$datu = json_encode($datu);
print_r ($datu);
}
```

Тут надо доделать success

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "/core.php?ajax=user_search",
  type: "POST",
  data: {"hel":hel},
  success: function(arsi) {
// это переделать
    var data = JSON.parse(arsi);
    document.getElementById('panel_user_search').innerHTML = data['name'];
//*переделать*


  }});
```

**Если лень читать: распарсить многомерный массив на подмассивы,  залить каждый подмассив в отдельный div**

Comment: Вы получаете массив, а обращаетесь как к объекту.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let success=response=>{
  let data=JSON.parse(response),
  holder=document.getElementById('panel_user_search')
  data.forEach(v=>{
    let div=document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML=v.name
    holder.appendChild(div)
  })
 }
 success('[{"name":"\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441","last_n":"\u041b\u0435\u0431\u0435\u0434\u0435\u0432","avatar":"\/user\/0M\/0K\/2\/pictures\/avatar\/8c16432d87bec8614f709ddba.jpg"},{"name":"\u0414\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0441","last_n":"lot","avatar":"css\/ico\/avatar.jpg"}]')
```

```html
<div id="panel_user_search"></div>
```

Вставить функцию `success` перед аяксом и заменить `success: function(arsi) {` на просто `success`

Comment: Можете объяснить разницу? ( с переменной крашит, но если взять содержимое переменной и вставить...всё ок                                           var damp = "'" + response + "'";
console.log(damp);
    let success=response=>{
      let data=JSON.parse(response),
      holder=document.getElementById('panel_user_search')
      data.forEach(v=>{
        let div=document.createElement('div')
        div.innerHTML=v.name
        holder.appendChild(div)
      })
     }
     success(damp)

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев переменная `response` существует только внутри функции `success`, а вы пытаетесь её использовать вне тела функции, из за чего она возвращает `undefined`. Вас, наверное, обескуражили стрелочные функции, чтобы вам было понятнее, вот как выглядел бы мой ответ на старом JS синтаксисе и с переменной: http://jsfiddle.net/q1Lyhknj/2/